# am getting error ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'UserEditForm' is not exported from './Register'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
hello guys here is my full code which i have written but cnt figure out the problem.

the error which am getting is   "./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'UserEditForm' is not exported from './Register'."
```

hello guys here is my full code which i have written but cnt figure out the problem.

```
the error which am getting is   "./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'UserEditForm' is not exported from './Register'."
```

hello guys here is my full code which i have written but cnt figure out the problem.

```
the error which am getting is   "./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'UserEditForm' is not exported from './Register'." hello guys here is my full code which i have written but cnt figure out the problem.

the error which am getting is   "./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'UserEditForm' is not exported from './Register'."

register.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { UserEditForm } from './User';


export  function LoginForm() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchUsers() {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.store.ellcart.com/users');
      const data = await response.json();
      setUsers(data);
    }
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);
  


  return (
    
    <div>
      <h2>User List</h2>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <tr key={user.id}>
              <td>{user.name}</td>
              <td>{user.email}</td>
              <td>{user.phone}</td>
              <td>
                <button>Edit</button>
                <button>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export function UserForm({ onSubmit }) {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
  
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      onSubmit({ name, email, phone });
      setName('');
      setEmail('');
      setPhone('');
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Add User</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Email:
            <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Phone:
            <input type="tel" value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export  function UserEditForm({ user, onSubmit }) {
    const [name, setName] = useState(user.name);
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(user.email);
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState(user.phone);
  
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      onSubmit(user.id, { name, email, phone });
    };
  
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Edit User</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Email:
            <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <label>
            Phone:
            <input type="tel" value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
          </label>
          <br />
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }



this code is from APP.JS

import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import { LoginForm, UserEditForm, UserForm } from "./Register";


function App() {
  return (
   
    <div className="App">
      <LoginForm/>
      <UserEditForm/>
      <UserForm/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Help me to fix out the problem as i have tried everything but cnt figure out why getting this error.
```

Comment: In your register.js you are also importing UserEditForm from "./User". You don't use it anywhere in your register.js code, but have other function names UserEditForm. You have name clash. Whether remove your UserEditForm import that is unused in register.js, or if you need that import make sure no name clashes happen. You can rename your UserEditForm component in register.js or give another name to import from import {UserEditForm as SomeOtherName } from './User';

Comment: Why do you have line `import { UserEditForm } from './User';` in `register.js`? Comment it for a test.